# Adding goupby transform result to an existing pandas DataFrame with each row representing a group

Tags: python, pandas

TL;DR - I want to mimic the behaviour of functions such as DataFrameGroupBy.std()

I have a DataFrame which I group.
I want to take one row to represent each group, and then add extra statistics regarding these groups to the resulting DataFrame (such as the mean and std of these groups)

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"Amount": [numpy.nan,0,numpy.nan,0,0,100,200,50,0,numpy.nan,numpy.nan,100,200,100,0], 
                          "Id": [0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                          "Date": pandas.to_datetime(["2011-11-02","NA","2011-11-03","2011-11-04",
                                                      "2011-11-05","NA","2011-11-04","2011-11-04",
                                                     "2011-11-06","2011-11-06","2011-11-06","2011-11-06",
                                                     "2011-11-08","2011-11-08","2011-11-08"],errors='coerce')})

    g = df.groupby("Id")
    f = g.first()
    f["std"] = g.Amount.std()
```

Now, this works - but let's say I want a special std, which ignores 0, and regards each unique value only once:

```
def get_unique_std(group):
    vals = group.unique()
    vals = vals[vals>0]
    return vals.std() if vals.shape[0] > 1 else 0
```

If I use

```
f["std"] = g.Amount.transform(get_unique_std)
```

I only get zeros... (Also for any other function such as max etc.)

But if I do it like this:

```
std = g.Amount.transform(get_unique_std)
```

I get the correct result, only not grouped anymore... I guess I can calculate all of these into columns of the original DataFrame (in this case df) before I take the representing row of the group:

```
df["std"] = g.Amount.transform(get_unique_std)
# regroup again the modified df
g = df.groupby("Id")
f = g.first()
```

But that would just be a waste of memory space since many rows corresponding to the same group would get the same value, and I'd also have to group df twice - once for calculating these statistics, and a second time to get the representing row...

So, as stated in the beginning, I wonder how I can mimic the behaviour of DataFrameGroupBy.std().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)

You can pass your custom function like this and get a grouped result:

```
g.Amount.agg(get_unique_std)
```

You can also pass a dictionary and get each key as a column:

```
g.Amount.agg({'my_std': get_unique_std, 'numpy_std': pandas.np.std})
```